# unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) on an empty line

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax

I am new to PHP, but I jumped straight onto a huge personal project that I'm having some slight issues with. Basically I'm trying to make a control panel with users listed into a table. It's worked perfectly before but suddenly it doesn't work, and I can't recall making any big changes. Pretty sure I'm not the first to encounter this error, but in my opinion it seems very strange, and I'd love some help to resolve it.

Running the code gives me the following error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /.../controlpanel.php on line 135

Quite basic, right?
Well the exact code I am using works perfectly when I run it from my local ubuntu webserver, but when I run it from my domain host, it throws the error right at me. When I look at the line (135) it is commented out and blank, so the error is misleading. It is 500 lines of code, so I'd rather not post the whole thing, though you can see it [here](http://pastebin.com/WMhT7QW4).

I've been looking through the document for hours tearing my hair out. Please look it over and tell me where I've done wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you look at the correct file?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: I am pretty sure it's the correct file. And I know a lot of people have encountered this error but I really find it strange as the pointing line is empty and I made it work on another webserver.

Comment: Sorry for this late answer, but it seems the problem was within the FTP. I have no idea what actually happened, but parts of the files went missing when transferred. I tried later, and it suddenly worked.